# Return multiple rows based on a stored value multiplied by possible options

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return multiple rows of information that can later be ranked. I have a product table (PRODUCT) that has product_id (PRODUCT_ID) and unit weight (PROD_UNIT_WGT) stored that i would like to return possible packaging quantities for, lets say 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, etc up to 310. Is this possible with out 309 unions?

The return should be similar to

```
select PRODUCT_ID, PROD_UNIT_WGT, 1 as QUANTITY, PROD_UNIT_WGT * 1 as TOTAL_WGT
from PRODUCT
where PRODUCT_ID = PROD_A
union
select PRODUCT_ID, PROD_UNIT_WGT, 2 as QUANTITY, PROD_UNIT_WGT * 2 as TOTAL_WGT
from PRODUCT
where PRODUCT_ID = PROD_A
union
select PRODUCT_ID, PROD_UNIT_WGT, 3 as QUANTITY, PROD_UNIT_WGT * 3 as TOTAL_WGT
from PRODUCT
where PRODUCT_ID = PROD_A
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table or temporary table and loop through your products. Code example below, I did this via Oracle Live SQL:

```
create global temporary table product(
    product_id NUMBER primary key,
    prod_unit_wgt NUMBER)
    on commit preserve rows;

create global temporary table temp_product(
    product_id NUMBER,
    prod_unit_wgt NUMBER,
    quantity NUMBER,
    total_wgt NUMBER,
    constraint pk_temp_product primary key (product_id, quantity))
    on commit preserve rows;

declare
    cursor product_cur is
        select product_id, prod_unit_wgt
          from product;

begin
    insert into product values(1, 3);
    for rec in product_cur loop
        for i in 1..310 loop
            insert into temp_product(product_id, prod_unit_wgt, quantity, total_wgt)
            values ( rec.product_id, rec.prod_unit_wgt, i, rec.prod_unit_wgt * i);
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;

select * from temp_product;

PRODUCT_ID  PROD_UNIT_WGT   QUANTITY    TOTAL_WGT
1   3   1   3
1   3   2   6
1   3   3   9
1   3   4   12
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column.

```
select PRODUCT_ID, PROD_UNIT_WGT, rownum as QUANTITY, PROD_UNIT_WGT * rownum as TOTAL_WGT
from PRODUCT
where PRODUCT_ID = PROD_A
and rownum < 311
```

Comment: This returned the correct information, but only for a single row with quantity 1. I assume because only a single row on the product table = PROD_A?

Comment: I see the problem. Let me give it some thought.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing query that writes query for you? I limited it to 3 (see the `connect by` clause in line #9) for better readability; you'd use any number you want.

```
SQL> with data as
  2    (select 'select product_id, ' || chr(10) ||
  3            '  prod_unit_wgt, '   || level || ' as quantity, ' || chr(10) ||
  4            '  prod_unit_wgt * '  || level || ' as total_wgt ' || chr(10) ||
  5            'from PRODUCT where PRODUCT_ID = PROD_A '          || chr(10) ||
  6            'union all ' val,
  7            level lvl
  8     from dual
  9     connect by level <= 3
 10    )
 11  select rtrim (
 12                xmlagg (xmlelement (e, val || chr(10)) order by lvl).extract (
 13                   '//text()'),
 14                chr(10) || 'union all ')
 15                result
 16  from data;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select product_id,
  prod_unit_wgt, 1 as quantity,
  prod_unit_wgt * 1 as total_wgt
from PRODUCT where PRODUCT_ID = PROD_A
union all
select product_id,
  prod_unit_wgt, 2 as quantity,
  prod_unit_wgt * 2 as total_wgt
from PRODUCT where PRODUCT_ID = PROD_A
union all
select product_id,
  prod_unit_wgt, 3 as quantity,
  prod_unit_wgt * 3 as total_wgt
from PRODUCT where PRODUCT_ID = PROD_A


SQL>
```